# PEM certificate changes after reading from file in C++

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

I have a PEM Certificate generated using OpenSSL. The certificate is read using fopen call in C++. The X509 object is then copied into an unsigned char array using memcpy, and the ascii values of the array are displayed.
When I repeat the same process (reading the file, and displaying the ascii values), the results differ. Results differ across executions, as well as in the same execution.

This is how I am reading the certificate

```
FILE* f_cert = fopen(filename.str().c_str(), "r");
X509 *tempCert = NULL;
PEM_read_X509(f_cert, &tempCert, NULL, NULL);
```

This is how I display the certificate

```
memcpy (temp, tempCert, sizeof(Certi));
for (int a=0; a<sizeof(X509); a++){
    cout << (int)temp[a] << " ";
}
```

Output-1:

> 16 216 64 1 0 0 0 0 128 223 64 1 0 0 0 0 160 223 64 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   1 0 0      0 208 232 64 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255
>   255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output-2:

> 16 216 212 0 0 0 0 0 128 223 212 0 0 0 0 0 160 223 212 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 1 0 0 0 208 232 212 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255
>   255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

But when I read the certificate's MD5, it stays the same. What could be an explanation for this? 
I need to insert this certificate into a Bloom Filter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use `X509 *tempCert` like you are using it. Its basically a structure with pointers, values, and flags on occasion. Try using `X509_print_fp`. Its appears its not documented (but it probably should be). Here's the signature: `int X509_print_fp(FILE *fp,X509 *x)`.

Comment: @jww So I assume that I was wrong in thinking that tempCert pointed to an 'actual' X509 certificate.

Comment: @jww The function you've mentioned prints a certificate to FILE object. But I want to print the certificate contents to a char array. How would this function be used for that purpose?

Comment: Also you read PEM in a wrong way. See basic examples to understand how to work with openssl https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/cms/cms_sign.c